# Merge array of objects when date is the same but add dynamic properties to new data structure

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
const measures = [
  { "13798494-value": 0.207, readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.211 , readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "13798494-value": 0.214 , readingDate: "27/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.123, readingDate: "27/06/2023" }
]
```

but I need it like this

```
const measures = [
    { readingDate: "26/06/2023", "13798494-value": 0.207, "4958469-value": 0.211 },
    { readingDate: "27/06/2023", "13798494-value": 0.214, "4958469-value": 0.123 }
]
```

I've tried the following but I cant get it to work

```js
 const reduceThis = measures?.reduce(
          (acc, item) => {
            const key = Object.keys(item)[0]
            const value = Object.values(item)[0]

            const queryResult = acc.find(
              (qr) => qr?.readingDate === item?.readingDate,
            )

            if (queryResult) {
              queryResult.results.push({ [key]: value })
            } else {
              let newQR = {
                readingDate: item?.readingDate,
                results: [{ [key]: value }],
              }
              acc.push(newQR)
            }

            return acc
          },
          [],
        )
```

But this comes back as

```
const measures = [
    { readingDate: "26/06/2023", results: [{"13798494-value": 0.207, "4958469-value": 0.211}] },
    { readingDate: "27/06/2023", results: [{"13798494-value": 0.214, "4958469-value": 0.123}] }
]
```

So I'm nearly there but cant quite get it.

The format "XXXXXXXX-value" is dynamic and the XXXXXXXX can be anything so we cant directly reference those values.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it fast use `Array::reduce` to collect items with the same readingDate in an array and in a map (for further quick access to add additional properties):

```js
const measures = [
  { "13798494-value": 0.207, readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.211 , readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "13798494-value": 0.214 , readingDate: "27/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.123, readingDate: "27/06/2023" }
]

  
const mapped = measures.reduce((r, {readingDate, ...props}) => {
  let item = r.map.get(readingDate);
  item ? Object.assign(item, props) :
    r.map.set(readingDate, r.arr[r.arr.length] = {readingDate, ...props});
  return r;
}, {arr: [], map: new Map}).arr;

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const measures = [
  { "13798494-value": 0.207, readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.211, readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "13798494-value": 0.214, readingDate: "27/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.123, readingDate: "27/06/2023" }
];

// Group the measures by readingDate
const groupedMeasures = measures.reduce((acc, measure) => {
  const { readingDate, ...rest } = measure;
  if (!acc[readingDate]) {
    acc[readingDate] = { readingDate, ...rest };
  } else {
    Object.assign(acc[readingDate], rest);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

// Convert the grouped measures object to an array
const sortedMeasures = Object.values(groupedMeasures);
```

Start reduce with an empty object `{}`. Get `readingDate` from current index and check if it already exists in the object. If yes, add the remaining values `...rest` from the measures object for the date. If not, add the date as a new key and assign remaining values then. Convert to an array afterwards.

Comment: @ChrisG start reduce with an empty object {}. Get `readingDate` from current index and check if it already exists in the object. If yes, add the remaining values `...rest` from the `measures` object for the date. If not, add the date as a new key and assign remaining values then. Convert to an array afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the array of object to build a new one item by item. As you iterate, if the current object does not exist in the new one, you add it, otherwise, you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the contents of the current object into the existing one.

```js
const measures = [
    { "13798494-value": 0.207, readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
    { "4958469-value": 0.211 , readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
    { "13798494-value": 0.214 , readingDate: "27/06/2023" },
    { "4958469-value": 0.123, readingDate: "27/06/2023" }
]

const reduced = measures.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const foundIndex = acc.findIndex(({ readingDate }) => (readingDate === cur.readingDate));
    if (foundIndex > -1)
        acc[foundIndex] = { ...acc[foundIndex], ...cur };
    else
        acc.push(cur);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(reduced);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be consolidated but is in my opinion easier to read

```js
let grouped = measures.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const { readingDate, ...rest } = cur;
  acc[readingDate] ??= { results: [] }; // initialise when needed
  acc[readingDate].results.push(rest); // add
  return acc;
}, {});
grouped = Object.entries(grouped).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc.push({ readingDate: key, results: value.results });
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script>
const measures = [
  { "13798494-value": 0.207, readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.211 , readingDate: "26/06/2023" },
  { "13798494-value": 0.214 , readingDate: "27/06/2023" },
  { "4958469-value": 0.123, readingDate: "27/06/2023" }
]
</script>
```